# Screen recording application

Tags: screen-recording, audio-recording

I am looking for software that can record my screen and also voice. 
I need to send to my mentor one project, and I need to record video and also audio and explain my project solution. I try with `Bandicam` but doesn't support audio record. 
Anyone who knows any software it will be very halpfull for me. 
Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/)

It is free and open source.

To setting it up, go to Task Setting > Capture Screen Recorder > Screen recording options, select video source and audio source.

By default it is using your microphone, but if you want to record internal sound, you can click install recorder devices. This will install virtual audio capturer, so it will record internal sound without noises as from microphone.

Answer (score 0):

I developed the utility in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx. But it has some issues with Win 10. So I corrected them and published at https://burakuysaler.wordpress.com/2020/03/16/screenrecorder-final-by-burak-uysaler/. As I don’t work at Microsoft anymore, I uploaded it to my Blog. Please try it, You will love it :)

Comment: Note to all: This brand new Software Recommendations SE community member quickly posted this recommendation multiple times.  Please use caution if visiting the specified site and trying the recommended software.  Please add comments if your experiences are positive or negative. Thank you.